# Using Shark machine learning library in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, machine-learning

I'd like to use Shark library in Visual Studio 2013. They provided the following example in Shark-3.0.0\examples:

```
#include <shark/Core/Shark.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    shark::Shark::info(std::cout);
}
```

But, I am getting the following error:

**error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'shark/Core/shark.h': No such file or directory.**

In fact, the header file name in *Shark-3.0.0\include\shark\Core* is *Shark.h.in*. But, if I change `#include <shark/Core/shark.h>` to `#include <shark/Core/shark.h.in>` then I get the following error:

**error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/version.hpp': No such file or directory.**

Comment: `*.foo.in` usually indicates that a file is intended as **in**put for some system / script that will turn it into a `*.foo` file. As such, and not knowing the first thing about this "Shark" library, did you follow that library's installation instructions, or did you just unpack it somewhere?

Comment: I followed the installation guide:http://image.diku.dk/shark/sphinx_pages/build/html/rest_sources/getting_started/installation.html

Comment: I clicked on Generate in CMake and generating done successfully!

Comment: "Generate" means you generated the build files. (MSVC solution, most likely.) You still need to actually *build* the library... (Are you sure you are up to using third-party libraries like Shark already? It seems as if you are still rather unfamiliar with basic building tools...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Shark](http://image.diku.dk/shark/) is a library that comes as source package, which (as per the instructions in its `README.txt`) requires compilation on the target machine:

> ### INSTALLATION / DOCUMENTATION
>
> The entry point to the Shark library documentation is located at
>   doc/index.html . For installation instructions, please click on
>   "Getting started" on that page. Short version of installation guide:
>   issue "ccmake ." in the main directory to select your build options,
>   and afterwards issue "make" in the main directory -- you should be
>   done (assuming Boost and CMake were installed). See the documentation
>   for detailed instructions.

More detailed installation instructions [available from the library provider](http://image.diku.dk/shark/sphinx_pages/build/html/rest_sources/getting_started/installation.html).

Note that Shark seems to depend on [Boost](http://boost.org), so install that first...

Comment: @user5388874: OK, let's take this slowly. *CMake does not build software.* It *generates build files*. On a Unix machine, it generates Makefiles by default, but can do generate e.g. project files for KDevelop or CodeBlocks. On Windows, it generates MSVC solutions, but could also generate NMake Makefiles. You said you "clicked on Generate in CMake". That means you most likely now have a MSVC solution (`*.sln`) that was not there before. *You have not yet build the Shark library.*

Comment: @user5388874: After you *have* built (and probably, installed) the Shark library, you need to add the *correct* directories to your MSVC setup -- first, the one containing `shark/Core/shark.h`, this is to mean, the directory where the `shark` directory is located in -- then the one containing `boost/version.hpp`. Then you need to add the *library* directories to your setup, so the libraries can be *linked* (or you will get "undefined reference" errors).

Comment: @user5388874: And me telling you this is an indicator that it *might* be a bit early for you to jump into the middle of what seems to be a rather complex, domain-specific tool library. No offense intended, but I've seen this pretty often over the years: You want to use what Shark is giving you (the racecar), and you're fast-forwarding through elementaries to get there (driving school). I'm just warning you that you might enjoy it more if you take your time (don't head for that wall of hurt over there).

Comment: Could you elaborate on adding library directories to setup. Should I put it in link dependencies (or) compiler dependencies?

Comment: @Sashank: "...you need to add the library directories to your setup, so the libraries can be *linked*." -- That would be *link* dependencies, then. ;-)

Comment: I added the library directory in Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories. Is there something else called link dependency? I am new to Visual Studio.

Comment: There is Additional Dependencies in Linker -> Input but it just has .lib files, not directories. Should I list all the .lib files that are shark/lib directory individually?

Comment: @Sashank: I don't even have *access* to Visual Studio, but from what I remember... *Additional Library Directories* would be extending the search path, i.e. list additional directories that the libraries listed in *Additional Dependencies in Linker -> Input* would be searched in. List only those *.lib files you need to get the project to compile. (Depending on documentation, figuring out which ones those are can be tricky. The idea is to not drag in anything into the compilation / linking process you don't absolutely need.) You CAN, of course, just list all of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a quirk of Shark's build system. There are two "include" folders in Shar's build folder. shark.h is in one of them. You'll need to add both folders as include directories or copy shark.h..

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem so I think I can attempt share my solution here. Indeed reading documentation does not help much. Please note that I use Shark on Windows environment. So if you use Linux environment, please consider my solution appropriately on your Linux platform.

Indeed what you need to do would be to add two things in your "Include Directories":

1. The path of your pre-complied shark library
   (Example: E:\Users\frank\Projects\SVM\code_c++\sharkTrial\shark_compiledFiles\include)
2. The path of your boost
   (C:\local\boost_1_59_0)

You can always do similar things in your IDE such as Eclipse. I hope it helps.

[image]